# write a spec for mandrill-api sending template email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, mailchimp, mandrill

I'm new to ruby and I've been trying to write a spec for simple function that sends email via mandrill-api (which is connected to Mailchimp).

I'm not using ActionMailer. only the mandrill-api gem.

I'm a bit lost, what's the perfect approach for this ?

I tried VCR, but I don't know how to make it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by using mocking the instance and also the parameters.

```
let(:instance) { MandrillMailer.new }
let(:mail) { double }
let(:mandrill_api) { double }
let(:messages) { double }
```

as well the output and the input of the methods that called mandrill

and

```
allow(messages).to receive(:send_template).and_return([{ 'status' => :sent }])
allow(messages).to receive(:send_template).and_return([{ 'status' => 'rejected'}])
```